# C# application doesn't run if out of build folder

Tags: c#

I'm having a weird problem.

I made a C# "Windows Forms Application" project from VS2012. It has some 3rd party DLL linked. The build was fine and I had no problem to run the exe file which was right in project's build folder, ie \myproject\bin\Debug\x.exe. But if I copied out the exe to anywhere and double click the exe, it didn't run any more. I tried this on my own PC and other's PC as well.

I am using windows 8 and .NET 4.5.

Please shed some light to me.

Comment: "It has some 3rd party DLL linked" && "if I copied out the exe"... could that be part of the problem?

Comment: Found something. As I suspected, if I copied that 3rd party DLL to the same folder where exe stayed, the app started running. Anything wrong with the linking?

Comment: "Linking" does not mean including. For detailed info please read Ivaylos answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When moving the executable of an application that uses 3rd party libraries, make sure you move the .DLL files along with it.

.NET applications use the local execution path to first check for dll dependencies, then query the Global Assembly Cache (a.k.a. GAC). The GAC contains all the built-in libraries of the .NET framework but custom libraries may also be added to it.

The common scenario of referenced DLLs, however, is to keep them along with the executable, since installing a library in GAC is a more-complex scenario and requires the prerequisites on any machine where the exe should run.

Comment: Thanks, Any way to pack both together as a standalone application, or do I need to use setup builder to do this?

Comment: Whatever suits you better. The common scenario is having a setup project (VS supports it) and bundle the application and dependencies along. A very quick and a lazy-man's way to do it is to use self-extracting archive with the contents of the bin folder as a setup, but that's not a very professional approach

Comment: GAC mean Global Assembly Cache . Not Application